# RecyclerView not showing data on first load

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load a list of data from local db using LiveData.

view.xml

```
... // constraint layout surrounds this
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_cities"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

here is how I am setting up the recycler view in the Fragment:

```
val citiesAdapter = CitiesAdapter(cityRepository)
with(view.recyclerView_cities) {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    setHasFixedSize(true)
    adapter = citiesAdapter
}
cityRepository.getAllCities().observe(this, Observer { list ->
    citiesAdapter.submitList(list)
})
```

adapter:

```
class CitiesAdapter(private val repository: CityRepository) : ListAdapter<City, CitiesAdapter.CardViewHolder>(CityCallback()) {
    class CityCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<City>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: City, newItem: City): Boolean {
            return oldItem.city == newItem.city && oldItem.stateId == newItem.stateId
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: City, newItem: City): Boolean {
            return oldItem.city == newItem.city &&
                    oldItem.stateName == newItem.stateName &&
                    oldItem.stateId == newItem.stateId &&
                    oldItem.selected == newItem.selected
        }
    }

    fun getCityAt(position: Int): City = getItem(position)

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    class CardViewHolder(cardView: CardView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(cardView) {
        lateinit var checkBox: CheckBox
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`cityRepository.getAllCities()` returns a LiveData> from my database.

I am using the ListAdapter that extends from RecyclerView so that it can handle managing the list for me. Also I am using the DiffUtil so that more granular notifies are called instead of just using notifyDataSetChanged.

Expected Behavior:
When I load the fragment, a list is shown in a RecyclerView with all of the cities in the database.

Actual Behavior:
When I load the fragment, an empty list is shown even though there are cities in the database. if I add a new city from the fragment, the list is populated with everything that was there before and the newly added item.

EDIT:
I hacked in an EditText to the xml and the list populates when I click it from the emulator. It does not work when I try and click it programmatically.

Comment: Could you show how do you populate the `LiveData` and also what does `citiesAdapter.submitList` please? I guess some fill action does not notify the Observer.

Comment: the livedata is populated by a Room query from my DAO. submitList is a library function of `ListAdapter<T, VH>` so I have no control of it.

Comment: Did you add `super(User.DIFF_CALLBACK);` in the adapter's constructor?

Answer (score 5):

I removed `setHasFixedSize(true)` and the data loaded as expected. Can anyone explain why that solved it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setHasFixedSize(boolean) Perhaps the fixed size at the time of this call is 0x0 pixels so that nothing is rendered.

Comment: Because your HEIGHT was set to WRAP_CONTENT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an observer in the lifecycle

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, getViewModelFactory()).get(getModelClass())
        attachObservers()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices to solve this issue.

First, you can set Fixed Size to false.

```
recyclerView_cities.setHasFixedSize(false)
```

Second, you can set the minimum height of your RecyclerView to your preferred size in your XML file.

```
android:minHeight="300dp"
```